# Converting Excel math to SQL in VBNet, ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, excel, vb.net, calculated-columns

I am trying to automate a process that is currently done mainly with excel files. These files have been used for a while and are customized just how the user likes them. I am turning this into a data driven VB NEt application and now and at the task of configuring all the computed columns to do the equations the user's excel spread sheets are doing currently.

The main ones needed that I can't find information on are STANDARDIZE, PERCENTRANK and STDEVA (atleast for computed columns- I have seen STEVA used in select queries)

Excuse me if there is documentation on this I can refer to, I searched google and stackoverflow and wasn't able to find anything. If you could point me to any documentation like this that might exist- that would be a huge help!

Comment: Some functions do not have a direct 1:1 new function. You can view all the functions here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/functions Some of them you will have to recreate yourself.